# Syntax error in FOR loop declare section

Tags: python, sql, postgresql, plpgsql, psycopg2

I'm attempting to use a `FOR` loop in Postgres to calculate data averages over a range of (variable) for each geolocation in my db. I am using python/psycopg2. Here is the code:

```
query ='''
DECLARE geoids RECORD;
BEGIN
    RAISE NOTICE 'Beginning average calculation';
    FOR geoids IN select*from census_blocks
        WHERE ST_contains((select geom from census_cbsa
             WHERE cbsafp10='%s'),census_blocks.geom)
        LOOP
        INSERT INTO temp_avgs VALUES
            (geoids,
            select avg(select alljobs from accessibility_results
            WHERE geoid=geoids
                AND deptime BETWEEN '%s' and '%s'
                AND threshold='%s')
        END LOOP;
END;
'''
```

The error I receive is

```
psycopg2.ProgrammingError: syntax error at or near "RECORD"
LINE 2:  DECLARE geoids RECORD;
```

If I remove this `DECLARE` statement (since I believe `LOOP` variables over selection values are automatically declared as `RECORD`), the error becomes:

```
psycopg2.ProgrammingError: syntax error at or near "RAISE"
LINE 4:   RAISE NOTICE 'Beginning average calculation';
```

How should I properly format this query?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Procedural solution with loop

You are using PL/pgSQL code but are trying to phrase it as SQL query. That's just not possible.

Use a [**`DO`**](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/sql-do.html) statement or (since you want to use parameters) create a [plpgsql function](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/sql-createfunction.html):

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION foo(_cbsafp10     ?type?     -- replace with ...
                              ,_deptime_from timestamp? -- ... actual data types
                              ,_deptime_to   timestamp?
                              ,_threshold    ?type?)
  RETURNS void AS
$func$
DECLARE
   rec RECORD;
BEGIN

FOR rec IN
   SELECT b.*
   FROM   census_blocks b
   JOIN   census_cbsa   c ON ST_contains(c.geom, b.geom)
   WHERE  c.cbsafp10 = _cbsafp10
LOOP
   INSERT INTO temp_avgs    -- you might add a target list for safety. depends ..
   SELECT rec.*, avg(alljobs)
   FROM   accessibility_results
   WHERE  geoid = rec.geoid -- assuming you join on column "geoid"?
   AND    deptime BETWEEN _deptime_from AND _deptime_to
   AND    threshold = _threshold;
END LOOP;

END
$func$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

Make sure you escape quotes properly in your client!

- LOOP variables over selection values are ***not*** automatically declared as anything.
- Replace your unnecessary subqueries.
- The immediate cause for your 2nd error msg: [`RAISE`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/plpgsql-errors-and-messages.html) is a plpgsql command, *not* an SQL command.

#### Superior set-based solution

This goes to demonstrate the basics of a plpgsql function. But, as @Gordon already supplied, just use a single `INSERT` statement *doing the same* instead. Untangled further:

```
INSERT INTO temp_avgs   -- you might add a target list for safety. depends ..
SELECT b.*, avg(alljobs)
FROM   census_cbsa           c
JOIN   census_blocks         b ON ST_contains(c.geom, b.geom)
JOIN   accessibility_results a ON a.geoid = b.geoid     
WHERE  c.cbsafp10 = %s
AND    a.deptime BETWEEN %s AND %s
AND    a.threshold = %s
GROUP  BY b.geoid;    -- assuming b.geoid is the primary key
```

Answer (score 0):

How about phrasing it as a single select.  Something like this:

```
INSERT INTO temp_avgs(geoid, average)
   select cb.geoid, avg(aj.alljobs)
   from census_blocks cb join
        accessibility_results ar
        on cb.geoid = ar.geoid
   WHERE ST_contains((select geom from census_cbsa WHERE cbsafp10='%s'), cb.geom) and
         ar.deptime BETWEEN '%s' and '%s' AND ar.threshold='%s'
   group by cb.geoid;
```

I'm not sure where all the columns come from, so the table aliases are a bit of a guess.

Comment: I thought about the possibility of phrasing as a single select, but I don't think that works - the data table structure has many values (rows) for each geolocation. Calculating the average of the entire data column would yield 1 number - I need an average value for each unique geolocation, which I don't think can be done without a loop.

Comment: @user3757974 . . . Oops, I left out that all important `group by` clause.  That should do what you want.